# Gaussian covariance matrix

Tags: reference-request

Assume a random vector $$X=(X_1,\ldots,X_p) \sim N(0,\Sigma)$$ with $\Sigma$ positive definite matrix. Is there literature regarding the covariance (formulas) of the form
$E[X_j^kX_{j'}^l]$? with $k,l \in \{1,\ldots, q\}$ for some $q\in \mathbb{N}$.

Additional Note: More concretely i am concerned whether a covariance matrix of the form $\tilde{\Sigma} = \left( E[X_j^kX_{j'}^l] \right)_{l,k, j,j'}$ is still positive definite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any couple $(j,j')$, it suffices to calculate the characteristic function of $(X_j,X_{j'})$:
$$\phi_{(X_j,X_{j'})}(t_1,t_2)=\mathbb{E}\left( e^{t_1 X_j +t_2X_{j'}} \right) \tag{1}$$
The formula of $(1)$ can be easily deduce from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definitions).

We notice that
$$ X_j^k X_{j'}^l \cdot  e^{t_1 X_j +t_2X_{j'}}   =  \frac{\partial ^{(k+l)}}{\partial^kt_1\cdot \partial^l t_2} \left(   e^{t_1 X_j +t_2X_{j'}}\right)$$

Then, the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left( X_j^k X_{j'}^l \right) $ can be calculated from the derivatives $(k+l)$ of the characteristic function at the point $(t_1,t_2)=(0,0)$:
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{E}\left( X_j^k X_{j'}^l \right) = \frac{\partial ^{(k+l)}\phi_{(X_j,X_{j'})}}{\partial^kt_1\cdot \partial^l t_2}(0,0)} $$

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot.

Comment: @statuser123 You're welcome. And if you need to calculate many $\mathbb{E}\left( X_j^k X_{j'}^l \right)$, then it's better to compute the characteristic function of $(X_1,...,X_p)$ (denoted by $\phi_{(X_1,...,X_p)}(t_1,t_2,...,t_p)$ and then
$$\mathbb{E}\left( X_j^k X_{j'}^l \right) = \frac{\partial ^{(k+l)}\phi_{(X_1,...,X_p)}}{\partial^kt_1\cdot \partial^l t_2}(0,0,...,0) $$